# How do I prevent vee 4 field validation from occurring on mount?

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I want to prevent vee 4 field rules validation on mount.

```
<VeeForm 
    :id="formId"
    @submit="onSubmit" 
    :validateOnMount="false"
>
  
    <VeeField 
        name="test" 
        :rules="testRule"
        :validateOnMount="false"
    />
    
</VeeForm>
```

testRule is always run on mount. How do I prevent this? validateOnMount="false" has no effect.

If there is no way how would I go about setting an ok or error class on a parent component. Neither of these classes should be put on the parent component element until the user has actually input something into the text input. I wish to do so using a 100% vue/vee pattern.

I currently set a flag within the validation function which triggers the parent error class to be applied on mount which is not desired. I can certainly work around this in a cludgy way by setting up my validation function to ignore the first pass but I'd rather not do that. There must be an easier way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @bitski This is super simple to test... console.log( 'created' ) in the created function, console.log( 'mounted' ) in the mounted function and console.log( 'testRule' ) in the testRule function. I'm going to look for another solution I think. I shouldn't have to cludge it.